# How to instantly review text inside input

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I've seen some sites that using jquery to review instantly any text wrote inside an input text field.

Here is example :-

where i write `a` it instantly shown at  `=> some_site.com/a`

[image]

when i write another letter `b` it instantly shown at `=> some_site.com/ab`

[image]

and so on anything i wrote instantly shown

[image]

But that is not all ! if i removed any text so the input field is empty
it shows `=> some_site.com/???`

[image]

This could be good for reviewing input text before submit the whole form

How to do such nice effect ?

if html form code is

```
<input type="text" name="txt" id="txt">
```

~ thanks for help

Comment: This actually does not have much to do with jQuery. You should learn about the [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keyup) DOM event.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: Use the [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event to monitor for changes then use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to update the text after `some_site.com/` (probably setting it to `this.value`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example

http://jsfiddle.net/ydzr8/

basically you want the keyup event to get the value from the text box

```
<input type='text' class='input'/> <div class="display">http://www.something/???</div>
```

Then

```
$('.input').keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val() === '')
  {
    $('.display').html("http://www.something/???");
  }else{
    $('.display').html("http://www.something/" + $(this).val());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged Mootools in this question, here is a Mootools way to do it:

HTML example:

```
<input type='text' class='input' />
<div id="result">http://www.mysite.com/<span></span>
</div>
```

Mootools:

```
document.getElement('input').addEvent('keyup', function () {
    var val = this.value ? this.value : '???';
    document.id('result').getElement('span').innerHTML = val;
});
```

// Option 2:

```
document.getElement('input').addEvent('keyup', function () {
    $$('#result span').set('html', this.value ? this.value : '???');
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JQNq6/)